# How best to divide different levels of a factor by one another in dataframe in R?

Tags: r, matrix, division

I am trying to divide the values of two different levels of a factor in R but I cannot figure out the best way to do so. I have the following example dataframe:

```
structure(list(road_type_MEC = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A Roads", "Motorways", "Other Roads"
), class = "factor"), section = structure(c(2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("CO2_forecasts", "NOX_forecasts", 
"PM10_forecasts", "speedvehkm", "traffic_forecasts"), class = "factor"), 
    Total = c(126976204275.87, 4488849757.15535, 28318632014.3604, 
    75124228527.6742, 2799787906.95208, 43699868192.4562, 96766663214.7388, 
    3181356853.12977, 2094202918.63916)), row.names = c(NA, -9L
), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`8933` = 8933L, 
`8934` = 8934L, `8935` = 8935L, `8957` = 8957L, `8958` = 8958L, 
`8959` = 8959L, `8981` = 8981L, `8982` = 8982L, `8983` = 8983L, 
`8999` = 8999L, `9000` = 9000L, `9001` = 9001L, `9005` = 9005L, 
`9006` = 9006L, `9007` = 9007L, `9023` = 9023L, `9024` = 9024L, 
`9025` = 9025L, `9029` = 9029L, `9030` = 9030L, `9031` = 9031L, 
`9191` = 9191L, `9192` = 9192L, `9193` = 9193L, `9524` = 9524L, 
`9525` = 9525L, `9526` = 9526L, `9527` = 9527L, `9528` = 9528L, 
`9529` = 9529L, `9530` = 9530L, `9531` = 9531L, `9532` = 9532L, 
`9533` = 9533L, `9534` = 9534L, `9535` = 9535L, `9536` = 9536L, 
`9537` = 9537L, `9538` = 9538L, `9539` = 9539L, `9540` = 9540L, 
`9541` = 9541L, `9548` = 9548L, `9549` = 9549L, `9550` = 9550L, 
`9551` = 9551L, `9552` = 9552L, `9553` = 9553L, `9554` = 9554L, 
`9555` = 9555L, `9556` = 9556L, `9557` = 9557L, `9558` = 9558L, 
`9559` = 9559L, `9560` = 9560L, `9561` = 9561L, `9562` = 9562L, 
`9563` = 9563L, `9564` = 9564L, `9565` = 9565L, `9569` = 9569L, 
`9570` = 9570L, `9571` = 9571L, `9572` = 9572L, `9573` = 9573L, 
`9574` = 9574L, `9575` = 9575L, `9576` = 9576L, `9577` = 9577L, 
`9578` = 9578L, `9579` = 9579L, `9580` = 9580L, `9581` = 9581L, 
`9582` = 9582L, `9583` = 9583L, `9584` = 9584L, `9585` = 9585L, 
`9586` = 9586L, `9587` = 9587L, `9588` = 9588L, `9589` = 9589L, 
`9593` = 9593L, `9594` = 9594L, `9595` = 9595L, `9596` = 9596L, 
`9597` = 9597L, `9598` = 9598L, `9599` = 9599L, `9600` = 9600L, 
`9601` = 9601L, `9602` = 9602L, `9603` = 9603L, `9604` = 9604L, 
`9605` = 9605L, `9606` = 9606L, `9607` = 9607L, `9608` = 9608L, 
`9609` = 9609L, `9610` = 9610L, `9611` = 9611L, `9612` = 9612L, 
`9613` = 9613L, `9617` = 9617L, `9618` = 9618L, `9619` = 9619L, 
`9620` = 9620L, `9621` = 9621L, `9622` = 9622L, `9623` = 9623L, 
`9624` = 9624L, `9625` = 9625L, `9626` = 9626L, `9627` = 9627L, 
`9628` = 9628L, `9629` = 9629L, `9630` = 9630L, `9631` = 9631L, 
`9632` = 9632L, `9633` = 9633L, `9634` = 9634L, `9635` = 9635L, 
`9636` = 9636L, `9637` = 9637L, `9653` = 9653L, `9654` = 9654L, 
`9655` = 9655L, `9701` = 9701L, `9702` = 9702L, `9703` = 9703L, 
`9725` = 9725L, `9726` = 9726L, `9727` = 9727L, `9749` = 9749L, 
`9750` = 9750L, `9751` = 9751L), class = "omit"), groups = structure(list(
    road_type_MEC = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A Roads", "Motorways", 
    "Other Roads"), class = "factor"), .rows = list(1:3, 4:6, 
        7:9)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
   "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

I am trying to calculate section$NOX_forecasts/section$traffic_forecasts for each road_type_MEC ("A Roads", "Motorways", "Other Roads") in the dataframe. I'm not sure the best way to proceed - any help would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: Perhaps this isn't exactly what you're searching for but `as.numeric` will let you treat a factor as a number. So if `x` and `y` are both factors, `as.numeric(x) / as.numeric(y)` is a valid way to divide one by the other. Though make sure the operation isn't modifying the level in strange ways, I've had data where as.numeric bumped all the levels up by one.

Comment: @CaioBrighenti `as.numeric(as.character())`, unless you want bugs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reshaping long to wide then calculate division across columns:

```
rdf <- reshape(section, timevar = "section", v.names = "Total", 
               idvar = "road_type_MEC", direction = "wide")
colnames(rdf) <- gsub("Total.", "", colnames(rdf))

rdf$div_result <- rdf$NOX_forecasts/rdf$traffic_forecasts

rdf
#   road_type_MEC NOX_forecasts PM10_forecasts traffic_forecasts div_result
# 1       A Roads  126976204276     4488849757       28318632014   4.483840
# 4     Motorways   75124228528     2799787907       43699868192   1.719095
# 7   Other Roads   96766663215     3181356853        2094202919  46.206918
```

If you need to format data back to long, use `reshape` again:

```
long_df <- reshape(rdf, varying = names(rdf)[-1], times = names(rdf)[-1], 
                   timevar = "section", v.names = "Total",
                   new.row.names = 1:1E4, direction = "long")

long_df <- data.frame(long_df[order(long_df$road_type_MEC),],
                      row.names = NULL)
long_df

#    road_type_MEC           section        Total id
# 1        A Roads     NOX_forecasts 1.269762e+11  1
# 2        A Roads    PM10_forecasts 4.488850e+09  1
# 3        A Roads traffic_forecasts 2.831863e+10  1
# 4        A Roads        div_result 4.483840e+00  1
# 5      Motorways     NOX_forecasts 7.512423e+10  2
# 6      Motorways    PM10_forecasts 2.799788e+09  2
# 7      Motorways traffic_forecasts 4.369987e+10  2
# 8      Motorways        div_result 1.719095e+00  2
# 9    Other Roads     NOX_forecasts 9.676666e+10  3
# 10   Other Roads    PM10_forecasts 3.181357e+09  3
# 11   Other Roads traffic_forecasts 2.094203e+09  3
# 12   Other Roads        div_result 4.620692e+01  3
```

Comment: I seem to be getting the following  error when I run this code: "Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  object 'NOX_forecasts' not found"

Comment: See update. Since `reshape` adds attributes to data frame object, `with` does not directly work.

Comment: That still appears not to be working. I get the following error when I run the top part of the code: `Error in reshape(section, timevar = "section", v.names = "Total", idvar = "road_type_MEC",  : object 'section' not found".`

Comment: *section* should be the name of your dataframe which I named according to your post *I am trying to calculate section section$NOX_forecasts/section$traffic_forecasts*. Using exact posted data frame dput (named *section*), code works perfectly. See demo: https://rextester.com/YUDIT41901

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that exists far better solutions, probably using Tidyverse dialect, but meanwhile here is a possible solution:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table (
  tib[tib$section == "NOX_forecasts", "road_type_MEC"],
  NOX_forecasts = tib[tib$section == "NOX_forecasts", "Total"],
  traffic_forecasts = tib[tib$section == "traffic_forecasts", "Total"]
)

DT[, Result := NOX_forecasts.Total / traffic_forecasts.Total][]

   road_type_MEC NOX_forecasts.Total traffic_forecasts.Total    Result
1:       A Roads        126976204276             28318632014  4.483840
2:     Motorways         75124228528             43699868192  1.719095
3:   Other Roads         96766663215              2094202919 46.206918
4:       A Roads        126976204276             28318632014  4.483840
5:     Motorways         75124228528             43699868192  1.719095
6:   Other Roads         96766663215              2094202919 46.206918
```

Please note that this solution assumes there is the same number of rows for each target-section.

Best regards,